# Rails/Active Record/SQLite 3 Text data type - stores value as array string

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, sqlite

I have a simple for set up that has a text area input that a user can input a basic journal entry. Everything submits correctly, however, when I output the database value it looks like this:

```
["Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet", " consectetur adipiscing elit. Maecenas vehicula erat sapien", " sed dignissim tellus porta ut. Sed a accumsan dui. Nam lobortis nibh a sodales scelerisque. Vestibulum sed convallis quam", " sed volutpat eros. Nam ac metus enim. Curabitur porta tortor ac nisi aliquam consectetur. Nunc vulputate", " ante ac gravida pharetra", " justo nisl efficitur odio", " quis auctor tortor felis quis nisi.\r\n\r\nInteger accumsan risus vitae nulla pulvinar", " vitae mollis nulla finibus. Donec tempor", " tellus vel pharetra ultrices", " quam felis mollis elit", " eget dictum turpis felis eu metus. Donec bibendum nibh ac nunc ultrices", " eu eleifend dolor euismod. Duis lobortis imperdiet commodo. Vivamus non purus sit amet massa scelerisque accumsan. Ut ultrices velit vel arcu tempor bibendum. Suspendisse sagittis orci quis sem ullamcorper", " ac cursus nulla pulvinar.\r\n\r\nInterdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Suspendisse lacinia tincidunt nulla nec lobortis. Duis nec tortor eget ipsum consectetur pharetra varius ut arcu. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Ut vulputate viverra nisi eget varius. Proin eget nunc sit amet diam sagittis ultrices. Vivamus vitae tempus lectus", " nec malesuada diam. Pellentesque efficitur nunc eu dictum lacinia. Etiam lacinia", " velit a varius sollicitudin", " leo sem convallis sapien", " vitae accumsan nisi mauris quis enim. Nulla sit amet eros felis. Vivamus blandit tempus lectus id eleifend. Etiam mattis pharetra nulla", " quis pulvinar augue fringilla vel. Mauris vulputate leo eget enim condimentum dapibus.\r\n\r\nSed consequat", " risus gravida consequat semper", " risus felis pulvinar erat", " sed dictum nunc odio nec sapien. Donec consequat eleifend orci. Aenean accumsan tincidunt faucibus. Ut elementum tellus ut felis vulputate tempor. Nunc tincidunt diam eget mi posuere", " at blandit nisl elementum. Nunc in mollis enim. Phasellus id pulvinar lorem. Nullam eu ultrices est", " in sodales ex. Vestibulum et massa et odio iaculis pellentesque eu elementum sem. Vestibulum venenatis efficitur pharetra. Ut non tristique arcu. Donec tincidunt metus non dignissim dictum. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet", " consectetur adipiscing elit. Aliquam id efficitur lorem. Donec porttitor cursus maximus.\r\n\r\nAliquam euismod pellentesque gravida. In volutpat arcu velit", " in varius tellus maximus sit amet. Proin in iaculis tellus. Nam a posuere dolor", " non rhoncus tortor. Mauris vestibulum venenatis congue. Mauris tincidunt facilisis leo", " et maximus mi egestas lobortis. Fusce vitae venenatis metus", " sed consequat augue. Vivamus non sem ultricies", " congue leo ut", " euismod augue. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Suspendisse ut suscipit nisl", " quis ullamcorper tellus. Cras maximus aliquam suscipit. Nam auctor erat et velit fermentum tristique. Ut eu tempus sapien", " dapibus fermentum sem. In non velit diam."]
```

I cannot figure out why it stores it this way. My understanding of that database type may be incorrect, but should it not store it as a string? Why does it convert it to an array then stores it as a string? Thank you in advance.

Yes agreed. Here is the relevant section of my schema. I've used this type before with problems before.

```
create_table "journals", force: :cascade do |t|
 t.string   "title"
 t.text   "body"
 t.boolean  "private"
 t.integer  "user_id"
 t.datetime "created_at", null: false
 t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
end
```

Comment: You might do well to post the relevant portion of your schema.rb. I use text type columns against sqlite3 and I never get an array of strings.

Comment: Are you serializing the field in model? or overriding accessor?

Comment: No I am not doing either.